# What lane do assassins play on?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've mostly played AD Carry on Bot lane and Offtank on Top lane, so I am unsure of where other certain types of champions should lane.
This is what I know so far:

- Top: Offtanks
- Mid: AP Carries
- Bot: AD Carries, Supports, Tanks

So, where do assassins like Talon fit in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assassins** don't work so well on actual meta. Playing such character type is challenging and the best case to pick such char is to counterpick.

As you write this character type can work on;

- **Top** - with focus on sustain which often criples damage output in late game (not reccommended IMHO)
- **Mid** - with focus on damage if have counter AP skills (reccommended if char have counter AP skill)
- **Jungle** - if such char have skills and big mobility but now we see more often offtanks like Alistar or Malephite on this "lane" (reccomended if char is viable)

Talon is used as a great counterpick on mid - **Cutthroat** skill - applies silence on target so it is great versus squishy **AP Carries**.

Good luck.

**Edit**:

[Here you can see](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lbnl_9CUTLY&feature=g-u-u) high elo gamer and his game at mid with **Talon** on **YouTube** and his opinon why **Talon** is great at mid :)

Answer (score 9):

Your current list isn't that true at all. In general this is the layout:

- Top: a champion which needs lots of farm but can stand his ground.
- Mid: a champion which needs a lot of farm but needs to be safe.
- Jungle: a champion which is good at jungling: good sustain, good ganks, good mobility, can get away with little farm.
- Bottom: two champions, one which can get away with very little farm and has utility (the support) and one which needs a lot of farm and is weak early on and needs babysitting (the carry) but gets strong later. Almost exclusively ranged carries exist (because they can hit from a reasonably safe distance).

So for example Talon can be played mid and jungle and to a certain extent top. He's not ideal for top because some bruisers like Riven and Irelia will make his life very hard and bot is unsuitable due to it's ranged nature. His sustain and clear speed in the jungle isn't great, but his ganks are good.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I'm sorry I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: In an afterthought, while this is well described lane information, it doesnt answer his question.

Comment: he did with the add on " For example Talon can be played mid and jungle". that exactly answers his question. Btw, i foun this very helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific lane for assassins, it depends on what type they are and how you play them. Often champions can be played in multiple ways, so the definition of assassin is quite broad anyways, some bruisers like Irelia can be played as assassins or as bruisers.

Usually such burst champions are played in mid or top lane because they need the experience from a solo lane since that is where a majority of their burst comes from. However, some assassins don't need the experience that much but rely more on the element of suprise so they are played in the jungle instead.

Top: Poppy, Pantheon, Xin
Mid: LeBlanc, Evelyn, Fizz
Jungle: Nocturne, Shaco

Top or Mid: Talon, Akali

Most mids can be played just as well at top if they got counterpicked at mid.

Answer (score 1):

it depends upon which assassin, you mentioned Talon, and he is usually either top or mid, but he is more effective mid.

In fact, a lot of assassins go mid: Akali, Katarina, Kassadin, Zed, Fizz, etc.

Assassins are also commonly in the jungle like: Shaco, Rengar, Kha'zix, and Evelynn.

And finally, some assassins go top, these are usually secondary assassins: Riven, Irelia, Xin Zhao, and Pantheon.

Also, some mid assassins can go top but again are better mid, such as Zed, Talon, Yasuo, and Katarina.